# Add Digital Signature to a PDF Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, digital-signature

I want to create a Swift application in which i fill a form and with the datas in the form i need to create a PDF and need to attach a digital signature to it. 
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to differentiate between Ink Signature and Digital (Certificate) Signatures. Former are basically useless in court, the latter are, if done right, as valid as a hand-signed paper.

With some clever tricks you can also combine an ink signature with a digital certificate signature.

Here's more info: [What Are Digital Signatures?](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/features/digital-signatures/). This will also explain what X509 is and how to prepare certificates.

Via using [Appearance Streams](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-appearance-streams/) you can combine such a digital signature with an ink signature as well. Apple's PDFKit has no support for certificates, so you'll likely need to get a 3rd-party solution or start reimplementing this via OpenSSL.